# Using self-signed certificate for Saml 2 assertion

Tags: single-sign-on, x509certificate, saml, saml-2.0

I'm working on Idp side of a Saml 2 SSO and as IdP we are supposed to post an assertion to the SP and It will be IdP-initiated.
There is a field in the assertion named x509certificate. 
My first question is that is this field public key itself or public key signed by a CA (Certificate Authority)?
And my second question is that if it is a public key signed by a CA then would it be safe to be self signed or better to be signed by a real CA?
And my third question is that is it better we provide SP with Idp Metadata or it is more safe to have certificate in any assertion request or maybe both?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the X.509 certificate embedded in the XML signature contained in the SAML assertion. If so, this is the base-64 encoded X.509 certificate that may be used to verify the XML signature. It's optional but typically included.

You should use a CA issued certificate. The SP has a trust relationship with your IdP. A CA issued certificate ensures it was your IdP rather than someone spoofing you who signed and sent the SAML assertion.

You would normally provide the SP with your metadata which includes your certificate. The SP will use this certificate to verify your XML signatures. However, as I said, there's no harm including the certificate in the XML signature as well although it's unlikely this will be used for the actual signature verification.

Comment: Thanks, If we provide SP using a secure channel (like USB) is there still need for a third party CA or we can just self-sign it?

Comment: This really becomes a business decision. I still believe you should use a CA issued certificate. Self signed certificates really are meant for testing purposes only. CA issued certificates aren't that expensive.

Comment: I see no reason to use a CA signed certificate if you exchange certificates over a secure channel. The only reason to use a CA is to verify the validity of the certificate. If you do this by comparing it to a previously exchanged one, there is no need to validate it using a CA and hence no need for the CS at all.